# Using Only NodeJS for including html,css and js files

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I basically have a Nodeserver.js file and 3 other files

```
1) index.html  -> '<path to Nodeserver.js>/public/index.html'
2) script.js   -> '<path to Nodeserver.js>/public/js/script.js'
3) sheet.css   -> '<path to Nodeserver.js>/public/css/sheet.css'
```

My Nodeserver.js as the following code:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log("Check 1");    
    if(req.url.indexOf('.html') != -1){ //req.url has the pathname, check if it conatins '.html'

      console.log("Entering HTML"); 
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
      });
    }

    if(req.url.indexOf('.css') != -1){ //req.url has the pathname, check if it conatins '.css'

    console.log("Entering CSS");  
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/css/sheet.css', function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
      });
    }

    if(req.url.indexOf('.js') != -1){ //req.url has the pathname, check if it conatins '.js'

      console.log("Entering JS");  
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/js/script.js', function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
      });
    }  

}).listen(8888, '0.0.0.0');
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8888/');
```

This code is supposed to display my HTML document along with my js, css files loaded into it.

But it does not do so.

I have tried removing the if statements i.e

```
if(req.url.indexOf('.html') != -1){ //req.url has the pathname, check if it conatins '.html'
```

In this case my html loads but my css and js files do not.
I've removed the if statements from those as well.
Node gives an error that says this :

```
Error: write after end
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:439:15)
at C:\Users\<USER>\Documents\WORK\Node\Nodeserver.js:20:13
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)
```

Please help. I want to load a html file with js and css without having to use NodeExpress.

This is how I have linked my files in the index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sheet.css">
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: your code works for the url: http://localhost:8888/index.html

Comment: Ummm... Thank you. I feel like an idiot.